# CSS box-shadow in IE6,7,8

Tags: css, css3pie

I know that its not supported ... i tried with [PIE](http://css3pie.com/).
I have put the PIE.htc file in same folder as CSS is and in the IMAGE folder.
The images get loaded with no problem using the "../images/image.png" path.

Here is the code:

```
.ma-footer-container { 
background: #fff;
margin:0px auto; 
color: #333333; 
padding-top: 10px; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33); 
box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33); 
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

And another try:

```
.ma-footer-container { 
background: #fff;
margin:0px auto; 
color: #333333; 
padding-top: 10px; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33); 
box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33); 
behavior: url(../images/PIE.htc);
}
```

No effect whatsoever. Looks like the box-shadow gets ignored completely. Does not show in IE developer tools...

Here is another try (using absolute path). The images im using have url like:
"http://www.myStore.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_kidstore/images/facebook_icon.png"

```
.ma-footer-container { 
background: #fff;
margin:0px auto; 
color: #333333; 
padding-top: 10px; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33); 
box-shadow: 0 10px 80px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33); 
behavior: url(/skin/frontend/default/ma_kidstore/images/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: Is PIE.htc being served with the correct Mime Type?

Comment: PIE.htc needs to be absolute, as IE resolves that relative to the document's URL, not the css files URL (thanks again, IE)...

Comment: Check your server logs to see if the correct URL is being requested for PIE.htc. If you're getting 404 errors in the log, you should be able to use them to work out what the correct URL should be.

Comment: there is nothing in system log. I have used the absolute path as suggested: "/skin/frontend/default/ma_kidstore/images/PIE.htc" as the images URL is "http://www.mystore.com/skin/frontend/default/ma_kidstore/images/facebook_icon.png" still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on this a while ago.
And the solution is: I dont give a rats ass about IE6,7 and 8.

Comment: finally, [an answer to my ie6 related problems](http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1352255060695_1432482.png). upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I was also not able to apply PIE using CSS, but the JavaScript solution helped me as a workaround.

In  tag of your HTML file,

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script src="styles/build/PIE.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->
```

and after that, or at the end of page before ending ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// providing CSS3 Pie behavior to elements
if(window.PIE)
{
  var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.ma-footer-container');
  for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++)
  {
    PIE.attach(containers[i]);
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: will try your proposal next week and post results.